# Change windows IP configuration with public IP addresses

Tags: windows-xp, router, tcpip, static-ip

In our office we have two internet connections. one for main use and one for backup. this backup connection equipped with WImax connection and cisco 800 series router.this is always ready to plug to the firewall. but i want to use this connection to connect one pc not the network. but this router IP is not local ip  how can i directly connect this router to my pc ? i tried to add router ip address as a default gateway but it's not working

Comment: We don't know enough about your network and PC setup to help you. There is no way for us to know how your office admin set it up. Therefore, you should ask the admin how to help you.

Comment: I do agree with CharlieRB.  It sound like you know enough to be a problem to the systems admin.  Like perhaps your company controls web access, but you know there is a spare router in the server room and you got a cable and a key.  Be careful, you could break something really bad.

Answer (score 1):

Each router has two IP addresses.  Internal and External.  The IP 123.232.72.83 is not within the authorized internal range, so I must assume this is the External IP.  This is NOT the IP address you want to configure as the gateway.  You need to configure the INTERNAL IP of the router, which you do not mention.

Try to be complete in your problem description and your answers can be more precise.  Also, sometimes doing the research to put together a good question, you will find your own answer.

If the primary gateway has an internal IP of 192.168.0.1 you will see it when you do the commanb:

> ipconfig /all

You can try using DHCP to pick up IP and gateway from the second Router.  You may need to turn DHCP  on.  But doing so can really harm the primary network if you somehow get connected.

It would help if you describe your situation perhaps "I don't have access to the router configuration" is the case?

The "secondary router" may not be a router, but a gateway, in which case, your ability to connect will be determined by the ISP.  They may provide DHCP, they may provide written parameters for you to set up your network (usually a router/firewall).  Be careful connecting directly to the Internet with a workstation.  You could get a nasty infection.  Remember, always use protection.

Comment: What did your Systems Administrator say when you asked her?